# Standard way to define recursive object shape using jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am using jsdoc to document function parameters. One function is recursive, and accepts an array of objects that can be nested to arbitrary depths. Here's a simplified example:

```js
const person = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Smith",
    children: [{ firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Smith", children: [......] }] // an array of person shaped objects with values for firstName, lastName, and children
}
```

I tried writing something like this, but I'm not sure how to handle the recursion. Is there a simple way to do this, or would I have to define a class for this object?

```js
/**
* @param person {{ firstName: string, lastName: string, children: person[] }}
*                                                                 ^ this doesn't work
*/
```

I'm just using `person` as an example -- in my actual app it's an object representing bulleted text with nesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`@typedef` tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef) to define types. It also supports [recursive types](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1726).

Your JSDoc could look like this:

```js
/**
 * @typedef Person
 * @type {object}
 * @property {string} firstname
 * @property {string} lastname
 * @property {Person[]} children
 */

/**
 * @param {Person} person
 */
```

Or shorter (but arguably less readable):

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{firstname: string, lastname: string, children: Person[]}} Person
 */

/**
 * @param {Person} person
 */
```

**Note** regarding "opting out of jsdoc `@typedef` exports": You may want to watch [issue #46011 of the `microsoft/TypeScript` repository](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46011).